# Is order guaranteed when two or more processes (apps) are waiting to put data in the same buffer?

Tags: java, multiprocessing

My project consists on 2 different clients sending messages to a server, all on the same machine.

All of the components have GUIs. When we click on a button in the clients' GUIs, they start sending messages.

The server receives those messages and sends a message to the buffer that tells the clients the buffer they can't write in the buffer so the clients go sleep.

When both clients are waiting for the server to send the "available" message, is it possible to guarantee order? By order I mean the one we click first to send is first one to actually send the message.

The clients go sleep for 1 millisecond every time they check the buffer and it's a not available message.

Comment: You should include some code. Why are you going to sleep for 1ms? A lot of socket/client io is blocking. How fine do you expect the synchronization to be? Let's say A clicks slightly before B, but B's click is received by the server slightly sooner.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming in this answer that the clients are different processes rather than 1 multithreaded Java program.

You would need some communication between the processes to guarantee order. You have several factors impacting timing: when the clients check the buffer, when the user clicks and which order the O/S happens to schedule the clients to add their messages to the buffer (which is, presumably, structured as a FIFO queue).

One (relatively heavy) way to accomplish this would be to use a mutex semaphore (meaning one maintained by the O/S or some other application, not within the JVM). The client would acquire a mutex semaphore when the user clicks and not release it until they have added the related message to the queue. This would guarantee that messages end up in the order in which the user clicks.

There are various third party libraries that wrap O/S semaphores in a relatively portable way.

Comment: Yes, they're both different processes. I appreciate your reply and it would actually work, but it's a project for my university and they won't allow us to use either threads nor semaphores. The clients send a structered message, defined by us, the students. We can add as many flags as we want. I just can't think of nothing that would assure order. I tried something but it wouldn't let me send 2 messages from the same client in a row, I would have to send a message from the other client before sending the other client's messages

Comment: have you considered just adding a timestamp to the message? Then the server could use a priority queue to process in order of time rather than order of arrival. It wouldn't guarantee order as the server could process a message before an earlier message is added to the queue. But with a small delay you can make out of order processing very unlikely.

Comment: @MiguelLeitão If all three of your processes are single threaded, then it sounds like you don't need any synchronization. Client A contacts Server, they start communicating. Client B just waits until Client A is finished, and the Server can accept another connection.

Comment: @matt how does Client B know that Client A is communicating with the server? Do you mean wait until the buffer is empty? That would seem to defeat the purpose of having a message queue.

Comment: @sprinter what message queue? If they're doing it single threaded and they need to maintain order, then Client B's connection won't get accepted until client A has finished. I commented here, not because of your idea, but because of their response to your idea.

Comment: @sprinter the Client A knows the Client B is communicating with the server because the Client B sends a message to the buffer with a flag. The Client A is reading the buffer and it only sends its message when that flag indicates "free channel". The Client B sends a clear message with that flag set to "free channel" when it finishes sending all its other messages.

Comment: @matt your first reply: yes it works but only in the first run. Imagine that I want to send messages from both clients while the server is executing an earlier message. Which client is going to write first when the server is done processing that earlier message? That's the order I was talking about. Maybe it wasn't clear and I apologize.

Comment: @MiguelLeitão If you only have two clients, then I don't see an issue. Either client A has an open connection with the server and client B is waiting, or client B has the open connection.